# NodeJS fs.stat inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, fs

I have what I would call a strange issue.. I guess it´s related to how node works asynchronously, but I can't figure out how to solve it..

I have the following code:

```
function traverse(dir) {

console.log("START: " + dir);

fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {

    list.forEach(function(element) {
        path = dir + "/" + element

        console.log("Loop files/folders : " + path);

        fs.stat(path, function(err, stats,) {

            console.log("fs.stats file path : " + path + " : " + stats.isDirectory())
        });
    }, this);
});

}
```

This gives the following output:

```
START: ./data/2017
Loop files/folders : ./data/2017/.DS_Store
Loop files/folders : ./data/2017/1
Loop files/folders : ./data/2017/2
Loop files/folders : ./data/2017/3
Loop files/folders : ./data/2017/Arendal2017.pptx
fs.stats file path : ./data/2017/Arendal2017.pptx : false
fs.stats file path : ./data/2017/Arendal2017.pptx : true
fs.stats file path : ./data/2017/Arendal2017.pptx : true
fs.stats file path : ./data/2017/Arendal2017.pptx : true
fs.stats file path : ./data/2017/Arendal2017.pptx : false
```

As you can see from the code, first I just give an output of the path string in the loop. Then, inside this same loop I do a stat for every path (element) inside the director. What happens here is when I use path variable in the fs.stat callback this refers to the last file "Arendal" and not each individual item in the loop. The isDirectory bool is actually correct according to the list of files and dirs, but its also important for me to get the correct path with the given isDirectory bool..

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you don't declare the `path` variable in the right scope.

Change your code to

```
list.forEach(function(element) {
    var path = dir + "/" + element; // <=== DECLARE IT HERE

    console.log("Loop files/folders : " + path);

    fs.stat(path, function(err, stats,) {

        console.log("fs.stats file path : " + path + " : " + stats.isDirectory())
    });
}, this);
```

For this kind of listing, assuming it's just a command line utility, you might get a clearer log by simply using the synchronous functions of `fs` (so that the order of calls is kept in logs).

Comment: Perfect, solved my problem. Actually not just a command line tool.  Trying to make a "smart" sync tool to AWS for very large file structures / many files. I guess async I beneficial.

Comment: @chranmat Then I'd suggest you have a look at promises and async/await to deal with such asynchronous actions (have a look at the other answer).

Answer (score 2):

@Denys Séguret answered your question

Just adding two things:

1/ It is a bad practice to put asynchonous code inside a loop

2/ Because you use of node I guess it support ES6 (depending on the version you use of it). Give it a try!

```
try {
  const stats = await Promise.all(list.map((element) => {
    const path = `${dir}/${element}`;

    console.log(`Loop files/folders : ${path}`);

    return fs.stat(path);
  }));

  stats.forEach(x => console.log(`fs.stats file path : ${path} : ${stats.isDirectory()}`));
} catch (err) {
 // Error handling
}
```

Comment: Good complements. I think a console.log is missing in the forEach loop.